# add attributes in HTML from property file in struts2

Tags: struts2

My action class is extending ActionSupport class from "com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport". I want to add an attribute of html tag inside JSP using properties file. below is an example.

```
<label>
<s:text name="getText('abc.def.userID')" />
</label> 
<input name="useralias" id="useralias" autocomplete="off" type="text" class="textfield" maxlength="Value From PropertyFile"/>
```

I want to set maxLength property using property file. Above, getText('abc.def.userID') is being translated successfully, but doing below

```
maxLength="getText('abc.def.userID.length')"
```

is not helping.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I'm sure that field isn't OGNLized by default; you could try using the OGNL escape sequence to force it.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton for advise.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using.

```
<s:set var="userIdLen"><%=getText('abc.def.userID.length')%></s:set>
```

and then, used it using OGNL in maxLength attribute like below.

```
<s:textfield maxlength="%{#userIdLen}" key="useralias" autoComplete="off"/>
```